# Hide or refresh element when all item are hidden ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a grid, with a menu and items.

If I hide all the items using the inbuilt menu, I would like to refresh the pagination so that it display 0-100 items.

The only way I found i looping over all the column, and if all are hidden, then I just hide the pagination, but it's a shitty solution.

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/I3fdjfJDCfoZ8MCH

(hide all the item using the grid menu on the right)

Right now I do this :

```
let allHidden = true;
lodash.forEach(column.grid.columns, function (col) {
    if (col.visible) {
        allHidden = false;
        return;
    }
});
if(allHidden)
    $scope.gridOptions1.enablePaginationControls= false;
else
    $scope.gridOptions1.enablePaginationControls= true;
```

but there is still the scrollbar, and actually I don7t like that solution

Answer (score 0):

You could disable both scrollbars, and change the loop a bit. 
Still a shitty construction (in your words :), because things will be messy when you decide to unhide any column... You would explicitly have to enable both scollbars again.

```
   gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged($scope, column => {
          if(!column.grid.columns.some(function(col) {return col.visible}))
          {
            column.grid.options.enablePaginationControls = false;
            column.grid.options.enableHorizontalScrollbar = uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER;
            column.grid.options.enableVerticalScrollbar = uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER;
          }
        });
```

BTW, you would have to inject uiGridConstants to use `uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER`.

Maybe there is a better solution to your problem, only it is not clear to me what you're trying to achieve here.